# Right shifting unsigned variables gives strange result - C / GBDK

Tags: c, bit-shift, unsigned, gbdk

I'm developing a gameboy game in GBDK but I've got a problem with right-shifting (8bit) unsigned variables. The code looks like this.

```
#include <gb/gb.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define GAME_OBJ_MAX_WIDTH 10
#define GAME_OBJ_MAX_HEIGHT 8

struct game_obj
{
    UBYTE matrix[GAME_OBJ_MAX_WIDTH];
    UBYTE width, height;
};

void draw_game_obj(struct game_obj *object)
{
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < object->width && i < GAME_OBJ_MAX_WIDTH; i++)
   {
       printf("BASE->%d\n", object->matrix[i]);
       for (unsigned char j = 0; j < object->height && j < GAME_OBJ_MAX_HEIGHT; j++)
           printf("Shift by %d->%u\n", j, object->matrix[i] >> j);
   }
}

void main() {
    struct game_obj racer;
    racer.height = 4;
    racer.width = 3;
    racer.matrix[0] = 10;
    racer.matrix[1] = 7;
    racer.matrix[2] = 10;
    draw_game_obj(&racer);
}
```

The [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnV0Z.png) is:

```
BASE->10
Shift by 0->235
Shift by 1->117
Shift by 2->58
Shift by 3->29
BASE->7
Shift by 0->235
Shift by 1->117
Shift by 2->58
Shift by 3->29
BASE->10
Shift by 0->235
Shift by 1->117
Shift by 2->58
Shift by 3->29
```

Basically any unsigned value right shifted (even by 0) changes to `235`, `117`, `58` and so on... I'm trying to understand why is that.

**Solution**

Issue fixed by assigning `object->matrix[i]` to separate variable.

```
void draw_game_obj(struct game_obj *object)
{
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < object->width && i < GAME_OBJ_MAX_WIDTH; i++)
   {
       printf("BASE->%d\n", object->matrix[i]);
       UBYTE u = object->matrix[i];
       for (unsigned char j = 0; j < object->height && j < GAME_OBJ_MAX_HEIGHT; j++)
           printf("Shift by %d->%u\n", j, u >> j);
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that initial value changes to exactly 235 but I do agree that giving further values was unnecessary.

Comment: Did you include a proper declaration for `printf()` in this module?

Comment: This is not `printf()` issue. I used `printf()` for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Most likely, something else is wrong in your program; memory was corrupted or whatever, and it is spilling over into something that damages the code currently shown in the question.

Comment: Added full code.

Comment: And does the problem reproduce with just that code shown and no other? With the code now in the question, replacing `#include <gb/gb.h>` with `typedef unsigned char UBYTE;` and `void main` with `int main` and running in an ordinary C implementation does not reproduce the output; the expected results are printed (10, 5, 2, 1 for the 10 values and 7, 3, 1, 0 for the 7 value). If that exact code is not working in your GBDK, then there is something wrong in your GBDK.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact code that generates this "error". I also tried ordinary C implementation (problem did not occur) and looked up in docs but did not found anything. What's funny, the left shift does work properly.

Comment: @Timax Suggest changing print to `unsigned u = object->matrix[i]; u >> j; printf("Shift by %d->%u\n", j, u);`.  I suspect `object->matrix[i] >> j` as an `...` argument is mis-compiling.

Comment: Note that technically `printf("Shift by %d->%u\n", j, object->matrix[i] >> j);` may be undefined behavior as `object->matrix[i] >> j` in an `int`.  The print format for `int` is `"%d"`.  Usually when the value is common as `unsigned/int`, there is no issue.

Comment: Yup, thats it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Timax Which comment fixed it for you?

Comment: @Timax: you changed the conversion format from `%d` to `%u` between the initial post and the current code, did this cause the problem? Did reverting to `%d` fix the problem? This is such an **unlikely**  explanation that we want to document a system with this behavior. What is the host system and `gbdk` tool chain version?

Comment: Assigning the `object->matrix[i]` to separate variable and performing right shift on it fixed the issue. The conversion format did not change anything in program's behaviour (retested with `%d` instead of `%u`). The host system is M1 MacBook Air 2020 with MacOs 12.3.1. GBDK is version 4.0.6.

Comment: Can you determine the exact version of the compiler (SDCC?) that's being used?  Can you post the assembly emitted by the compiler?  This starts to sound like a compiler bug, as assigning to a different variable shouldn't change anything.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: The `%d` vs `%u` question came up recently in another comment thread, and someone pointed me to C17 6.2.5 (9) which appears to guarantee that a positive `int` has the same representation as the corresponding `unsigned int` and therefore may be passed wherever `unsigned` is expected.  So I don't think it's actually UB.  And in any case it does not appear to have been the issue.

Comment: @NateEldredge Same encoding for positive values is not enough to avoid UB as the passing mechanism may differ - even though unlikely with `"%d"` vs. `"%u"`.  IAC, 1) my comment already alluded to that with "_may_ be undefined behavior" and "Usually when the value is common as unsigned/int, there is no issue"  2) _something_ is amiss in OP's code.  Useful to eliminate the [usual suspects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtSmfws0_To).

Comment: @Timax  Good you have a fixed, yet I think your are coding around a compiler bug.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Well, the footnote says "The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions [...]".  I know it isn't normative, but an implementation that used different passing mechanisms for `signed int` and `unsigned int` would appear to violate at least the spirit of the standard.

Comment: @NateEldredge What is needed is a good question/answer to address this - perhaps one exist?

Comment: @NateEldredge `sdcc -v` gives `SDCC : z80/gbz80 4.1.6 #12539 (Mac OS X x86_64)` (so it must be running under rosetta in my case). If you mean assembly source code, here it is https://pastebin.com/xx3Di4UJ (this is without the fix).